# Convert Scheme to C++

Tags: c++, lambda, scheme, translate

I was given an assignment where I have to convert a Scheme function into a C++ function. Here is the Scheme function:

```
(DEFINE someFunction
   (LAMBDA (n)
      (IF (>= n 0)
         n
         (- 0 n))))
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but DEFINE binds a name, `someFunction`, to a LAMBDA expression, `n`. If `n` is greater than or equal to 0 then `n` is simply returned. Otherwise, `0 - n` is returned.

Here is what I came up with when I converted it to C++:

```
int someFunction() {
   int n;
   if (n >= 0) 
      return n;
   else
      return (0 - n);
}
```

Am I getting this right? Any tips would be helpful! I want learn what I am doing wrong so don't hold back.

Comment: In the Scheme code the variable `n` is considered an argument to the function itself, if I read some documentation correctly. Your C++ code uses `n` as a local and more importantly *uninitialized* variable. Uninitialized local (non-static) variables in C++ will have an *indeterminate* (seemingly random or garbage) value, and using such variable without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And if I understand your function correctly, it's equivalent to [`std::abs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs). Unless you have a school or book exercise then always use standard functions instead of inventing your own.

Answer (score 2):

You missed one issue: the `n` in the lambda expression is a function argument. In your C++ code you declare it as a local variable (which is not initialised, so has an undefined value)

A better solution would be:

```
int someFunction(int n) {
   if (n >= 0) 
      return n;
   else
      return (0 - n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The lambda expression does not have a name; it is a function that takes one parameter, and the parameter is called "n".
(`n` is not a local variable.)

You forgot to make `n` a parameter in the C++ version.

The "most equivalent" C++ version would be

```
auto someFunction = [](int n) { return n >= 0 ? n : -n; };
```

but you're probably expected to write

```
int someFunction(int n) {
    return n >= 0 ? n : -n;
}
```